# How to implement a parallel task queue with returning result?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have a webserver with incoming requests for data processing.
The processing must be performed by a stateful worker (e.g. an exclusive database connection), but an arbitrary number of workers can run in parallel.

How do I dispatch work to a shared task queue, and return a result?
Ideally this uses async-await and without polling.
Each worker run should run on a separate thread.

I've read about ThreadPoolExecutor, but the API is extraordinarily complicated, requiring ExitStack and `__enter__` / `__exit__` etc; I thought about writing an abstraction [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76684285/22296712), but it requires me to duplicate the API (of the "Backend" onto the "BackendContainer".

Are there better alternatives?

Pseudocode:

```
workers = []
workers.append(start_worker(db1))
workers.append(start_worker(db2))
workers.append(start_worker(db3))
workers.append(start_worker(db4))

async def request(data):
  return await any_worker_do_work(data)


async def any_worker_do_work(data):
  # ?

def worker_do_work(data)
  # synchronous
  return self.db1.do_work(data)

# this should run on different workers
print("Result: " + str(request("hello")))
print("Result: " + str(request("hello")))
print("Result: " + str(request("hello")))
print("Result: " + str(request("hello")))
print("Result: " + str(request("hello")))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: as I know you don't have to use `__enter__ / __exit__ ` to run `ThreadPoolExecutor` - you can create it in normal way `pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(...)`

Comment: Python is standard module [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) - did you try it? It seems there is also `asyncio.Queue`

Comment: @furas AFAIK, it's necessary, in order for the worker to be stateful (thread.local variables).

Comment: @furas When a worker dequeues from a queue, how does it return a result?

Comment: you can use second queue to send results. And if you use one worker then you can use the same queue to send result.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is specifically a solution for parallel workers.